# In Spring data rest is possible to add nested @OneToMany object to parent over POST /parent/{parentId}/nested?

Tags: rest, one-to-many, spring-data-rest, spring-web

I have Parent and Nested objects. I can get list of nested, using `GET /parent/{parentId}/nested` but I cannot POST/PUT to it with success. On POST result I get HTTP 204 and parent have empty list of nested objects.

In logs I see that Hibernate do not insert anything in DB.
During debugging I see that Jackson Object Mapper for deserealization getting "`org.springframework.hateoas.Resources<java.lang.Object>`" as JavaType.

Here is real example of my POST:
`curl 'http://localhost:8000/api/users/402880e554b8f7960154b8f7adbc0000/orders/' -i -X POST -H 'Authorization: Basic OLOLO==' -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'deviceCurrencyCode: USD' -H 'Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8' -d '{"orderPrice": 0,"tax": 0,"shippingCost": 0,"credits": 0,"addresses": [{"firstName": "Figli","lastName": "Migli","zipCode": "5555","city": "Riga","country": "Tlmltr","phone": "7777","address": "Adddr"}],"status": "status"}'`

I know that it is possible to do `POST /nested '{"parent":"/link/to/parent"}'`. But if it is way to GET nested objects over parent, why I cannot POST/PUT/PATCH them this way? I checked, is it RESTfull, and seems it is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a a section ["The association resource"](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.association-resource) in the spring data rest documentation that tells you what is possible on this resource. And creating a new child and associating it is not possible.

I do not know the why this is.

The only way (I know of) to get this behaviour is to implement a custom controller that does that for you. (Make sure you do not use the `@RequestMapping` annotation on class level on your custom controller to not override more spring data rest functionality than you want to)

Comment: Thanks! Yes, probably I need to create controller for this.